# Wrong picture default in messages can't change

Tags: instant-messaging

I accidentally set my text message pictures to open to a printer.   I have tried everything I can think of and I can't change the default back so I can't open any pictures now

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to **clear defaults**

1. Navigate to **App Settings** (Probably **Settings** > **Apps**)
2. Select **the printer app** that opens
3. Scroll down till you see the **Clear Defaults** button. Press it.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: screenshot]

This should stop the app from opening by default, allowing you to specify another app to open it.